# Python, Selenium: Clicking on the next link in for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from tabulate import tabulate
import os
import time

class ITADBot:
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')

    self.base_url = 'https://www.isthereanydeal.com'

def _nav(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)

def scrape(self, connect=False):
    self._nav(self.base_url)
    time.sleep(2)
    
    result_iter = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('title')
    for child in result_iter:
        child.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'noticeable')]").click()
        
        time.sleep(5)
        
        self.driver.back()
        
        time.sleep(4)

bot = ITADBot()
bot.scrape(connect=True)
```

Just starting to get into webdriver and Selenium. I'm trying to click on the next link in that list of elements, but every time the loop iterates, it clicks on the first link.

How do I get it to go to the next element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Maybe I am a bit off-topic, but I would suggest an alternative solution, given the structure of the website that you are trying to scrape. In particular, I would use `selenium` to get all game page links, then I'd loop within the links, and get the info page by page with `requests` (which is waaaay faster than `selenium`, and doesn't need any `time.sleep()` to upload the pages. Finally, given that the task is particularly easy, I would get rid of the class + functions structure of the code (even though it is optimal from a pythonic perspective, if you just started you might want to go step by step with a plain code, then add a function, a class, and so on).

Below you may find a MWE that gets all links from 'www.isthereanydeal.com' and loops over all resulting links

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.isthereanydeal.com')
time.sleep(2)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5 # scroll each # 

# Get scroll height
last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
## SCROLL DOWN UNTIL IT FINISHES ##
while True: 
    # Scroll down to bottom
    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height: # scroll down until the end 
        break
    last_height = new_height

result_iter = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('noticeable')
links = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in result_iter] # get all game links
driver.close()

for l in links:
    r = requests.get(l) # get the game page
    # DO WHATEVER YOU HAVE TO DO IN THE GAME PAGE #
```

Comment: So each game page becomes a response object... How do I read through it now and pull out text?

Comment: It depends on what you want to extract from the page. The easiest way is by using `Beautifulsoup` from the package `bs4`, and proceed by parsing each page

Answer (score 0):

```
result_iter = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'noticeable')]")
for child in result_iter:
    child.click()
```

Found out only xpath will return a list.